# Fatal error: Class: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries

consider I create a native library (let's call it testLib) containing two classes called JNITestLib.h and JNITestLib.cpp. This library uses another shared library develop by someone else (let's call it libotherLib.so) containing two classes called OtherLib.cpp and OtherLib.h

Below my files

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := otherLib-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/library/libotherLib.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := testLib

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := otherLib-prebuilt

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += com_example_JNITestLib.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

JNITestLib.cpp :

```
#include "com_example_JNITestLib.h"    
#define LOG_TAG "Test"

JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_JNITestLib_startTest
(JNIEnv *env, jobject)
{
    ALOGD( "startTest JNI");    
}
```

JNITestLib.h :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "Debug.h" 
#include "OtherLib.h" //Problem here!!!!  

JNIEXPORT void Java_com_example_JNITestLib_startTest
(JNIEnv *env, jobject);
```

My problem is I get the following error after execute : ndk-build -C [project_path]/app/src/main/jni/ :

```
fatal error: OtherLib: No such file or directory
#include OtherLib.h
        ^
```

I also tried to change my Android.mk file like :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := testLib

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += com_example_JNITestLib.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -l$(LOCAL_PATH)/library/libotherLib.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But get :

```
This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the current module
```

Notice I cannot get OtherLib.h because it is included in the libotherLib.so

Does anyone have any idea to solve my problem please?

Answer (score 1):

You need the header files for libotherLib.so if you want to include them in your C++ code. Once you have the header files, you should add a line to Android.mk that tells the compiler where to look for includes:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := testLib

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := otherLib-prebuilt

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += com_example_JNITestLib.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := <path to a directory containing the headers>

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: The thing is i do not have the header file. This native lib is a 3rd lib shared by another person

Comment: It's possible to use a shared library without the appropriate headers, but ill-advised. I would ask that person to send you the header files.